# error in objConnect.Sql = Properties.Settings.Default.SQL;

Tags: c#, sql

I have a project for my graduate where I need to work with database.

I wrote this code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace _11111
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        DatabaseConnection objConnect;
        string conString;
        DataSet ds;
        DataRow dRow;
        int MaxRows;
        int inc = 0;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();                
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                objConnect = new DatabaseConnection();
                conString = Properties.Settings.Default.EmployeesConnectionString;
                objConnect.connection_string = conString;
                objConnect.Sql = Properties.Settings.Default.SQL;
                ds = objConnect.GetConnection;                

                MaxRows = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
                NavigateRecords( );
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
            }    
        }

        private void NavigateRecords()
        {
             dRow = ds.Tables[0].Rows[inc];
             txtFirstName.Text = dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(1).ToString();
            txtSurname.Text = dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(2).ToString();
            txtJobTitle.Text = dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(3).ToString();
            txtDepartment.Text = dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(4).ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

The error says:

> Error 1   '_11111.Properties.Settings' does not contain a definition for 'SQL' and no extension method 'SQL' accepting a first
>   argument of type '_11111.Properties.Settings' could be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  D:\c#
>   project\11111\11111\  33  62  11111

I don't know where to add this in the setting section `"SELECT * FROM tbl_employees"`

Comment: can you clarify DatabaseConnection, it's like class file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows Form, there's a section called Settings, where you can define your properties as a key/value pair. In your code, you just call the key to get the corresponding value. Your error message states that there's no key called 'SQL' in your properties. To add your custom key do the following:

- Open Solution Explorer.
- Right Click on your Project Name and select, **Properties**.
- In your Properties window, select the Settings option. This will open the settings panel where you can add, edit, & delete custom settings.
  [image]

Comment: thanks but what  should i write in the settings

Comment: i did it thanks so much ^_^

Answer (score 0):

```
 using (con = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.Connection))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = Properties.Settings.Default.Sqlqry;
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    con.Open();
                    da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    da.Fill(ds);
                    foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(dr[0].ToString());
                    }
                }

            }
```